# Is the subspace of open maps dense in the space of bounded operators between a Hilbert space and itself?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, representation-theory, hilbert-spaces

I'm trying to prove Schur's lemma for unitary representations of a topological group. I've already read the standard proof, but I am trying to generalize the argument used for finite-dimensional representations (which is apparently not the standard approach).

I was able to prove that, if the set $\mathcal{O}(V)$ of open bounded linear operators $V \to V$ is dense in the Banach space $\mathcal{B}(V)$ of bounded operators $V \to V$ then Schur's lemma holds. However, I'm not convince $\mathcal{O}(V)$ is always dense in $\mathcal{B}(V)$. My question is: is this the case? In other words, is the space of open bounded operators always dense in the space of bounded operators between a Hilbert space and itself?

If this is case, is there a name for this result? If this is not the case generally, is there some condition one could impose on $V$ to get the desired result?

Thanks in advance ️

**If you want more context**: One can adapt the argument used for finite-dimensional representations to show every open representation homomorphism between an irreducible unitary representation $V$ and itself is a scalar multiple of the identity. The question then is: is every other representation homomorphism $V \to V$ a scalar multiple of the identity? If $\mathcal{O}(V)$ is dense in $\mathcal{B}(V)$ then the general result would follow almost immediately from the (not necessarilly true) fact that we can approximate every bounded operator with open bounded operators.

Comment: I'm not sure how your proposed application would work.  Even if you know that every bounded operator can be approximated by open bounded operators, why would that mean that every representation homomorphism can be approximated by open representation homomorphisms?

Comment: That's a great question @EricWofsey. The idea is that every (continuous) representation homomorphism is a bounded operator, so the closure of the intersection of the set of all open operators with the set of all (continuous) representation homomorphisms (i.e. the set of all open representation homomorphisms) should be dense in the set all (continuous) representations homomorphisms.

Comment: I should note that when I say "representation homorphism" I really mean "continuous (i.e. bounded in the case of unitary representations) representation homorphisms"

Comment: That just doesn't work at all though.  For instance, $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, but there are plenty of subsets $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ such that $A\cap \mathbb{Q}$ is not dense in $A$ (e.g., $A=\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$).

Comment: @EricWofsey you're right. Also, thanks for your answer!

Comment: @EricWofsey The proposed application would follow if I was able to prove $\mathcal{O}(V) \cap \operatorname{End}_G(V)$ is dense in $\operatorname{End}_G(V)$, correct? This is clearly the case (because of Shur's lemma), but perhaps showing it without using Shur's lemma is not viable.

Comment: Yes, that would suffice.

Comment: In fact, I now realize my argument would (probably) work if I was able to prove the space of bounded representation homomorphisms with closed range is dense in the space of bounded representation homomorphisms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you want to use the norm topology on $B(V)$ then this is not true when $V$ is infinite-dimensional.  Let me note first that by the open mapping theorem, a bounded operator $V\to V$ is an open map iff it is surjective.  Now suppose $T:V\to V$ is any non-surjective operator that has a left inverse $S$ (for instance, $T$ could be the right shift operator $\ell^2\to\ell^2$ which has the left shift $S$ as a left inverse).  Note that $S$ cannot be injective, since $ST=1$ means that $S$ must be surjective already on the image of $T$ but that image is not all of $V$.  Now note that if $E$ is any operator of sufficiently small norm, $S(T+E)=1+SE$ is invertible, since the set of invertible operators is open in the norm topology.  This implies that $T+E$ cannot be surjective, since if $T+E$ were surjective, then the non-injectivity of $S$ would imply that $S(T+E)$ is not injective.  Thus, every operator sufficiently close to $T$ (in the norm topology) fails to be surjective.

(If you want to use a weaker topology then surjective operators are probably trivially dense.  For instance, a basic open set in the strong operator topology on $B(V)$ only constrains your operator on a finite-dimensional subspace, so you can freely define it to be surjective on the orthogonal complement of that subspace.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I'm particularly grateful for the detailed explanation of the counterexample. I was indeed talking about the norm topology in $\mathcal{B}(V)$